# Why is "Calais" not written "Calet"?

Tags: prononciation, noms-propres, toponymes

Regarding the name of the city in northern France, I was wondering why it is written Calais and not Calet, since the pronunciation should be the same.

Comment: Why not ? We also say "Palais" for a "Palace", "balai" for "broom"... Why should it be "Calet" ?

Comment: Because then, someone would pop up here and ask why "Calet" is not written "Calais", since the pronounciation should be the same.

Comment: I learned at school that `et` is pronounced more like `é` and `ais` is more like `è`, so for me, it isn't the same.

Comment: @ThomasWeller: I think you might have learned that wrong. As far as I know, both -et and -ais are pronounced as è.

Comment: @sumelic > I can at least think of the exception of "et" word which is pronounced as "é".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems the origin of "**Calais**" is not very clear ([source](http://opalecalais.free.fr/france_calais/page3_presentation/P3_1/P3_histoire.html#origine)):

> Selon les époques, la commune a porté différents noms. Le plan ci-dessus, représentant une partie de la Gaule belge en 1616, désigne Calais par Caletum. Ce nom aurait lui-même pour origine Calesium et Calitius, «Ca(l)» désignant le quai, lieu ou port (saxon), et «itius» le nom même du port.
>   On trouve aussi pour désigner Calais : Cales, en flamand occidental, ou encore Kales, en néerlandais, et Kaleis, en vieux français..

And from a second [source](http://www.calais.ws/FrHistory.html) :

> Calais doit à sa position géographique le rôle important qu'elle a joué dans l'Histoire.
>   Des silex taillés ou polis des tombes d'hommes primitifs trouvés sur les hauteurs du Calaisis montrent que cette partie du continent fût habitée dès les temps préhistoriques. L'origine du nom de Calais est toutefois des plus obscures. Certains la font dériver du celtique Kal ou du saxon Keel, signifiant "embouchure". Suivant d'autres, (et c'est la version la plus probable car Calais est appelée "Caletum" sur une ancienne carte), les "Calètes" ou "Cauchois", venus, selon les commentaires de César, aider les Morins (habitants des Mers ou des marais) à s'opposer à l'invasion romaine, se seraient établis sur ce point peu peuplé, y fondèrent une colonie à laquelle ils donnèrent leur nom ; celui-ci se transforma graduellement pour devenir Calais.

The ending "**et**" became "**ais**", and may just be an esthetic preference...

Comment: [Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calais#Toponymie) semble également soutenir les différentes propositions et la conclusion, en s'appuyant sur des sources autres que celles citées (je n'ai pas vérifié si celles-ci s'appuyaient sur les même sources que Wikipédia...).

Answer (score -3):

Because it's French, not English, and that's the way the French spell it. The sound of "ais" is the sound of a long "a".

Comment: Small correction: the sound of "ais" actually varies depending on the region. It's pronounced like a long "a" in the Marseilles area, but almost everywhere else (including in other countries) it's pronounced like the "e" in "bed".